# How can I show data from 2 level child component by clicking a button in the main instance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Let's say I have the main instance, a child component called "movie-card" and another child component of "movie-card" called "link-btn". The thing is I want to build a selector looping the "link-btn" component with v-for, and also I want to have a button in the main instance that show the data selected with every "link-btn" component. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <movie-card
                v-for="(movie, index) in movies"
                key="index"
                :movie="movie"
                :title="movie.title"
                :description="movie.desc"
                :review="movie.review">
            </movie-card>
            <a>BUTTON TO SHOW REVIEWS SELECTED</a>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.4.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('movie-card', {
    props: ['movie', 'title', 'description', 'review'],
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>
            <link-btn
                v-for="(review, index) in movie.reviews"
                :index="index"
                :review="review"
                key="review"
                @updateIndex="updateI($event)"
                @updateReview="updateR($event)">
            </link-btn>
            <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
        </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            selectedIndex: '',
            selectedReview: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateI(e) {
            if(e + 1 === this.selectedIndex) {
                this.selectedIndex = ''
            } else {
                this.selectedIndex = e + 1
            }
        },
        updateR(e) {
            if(e.id === this.selectedReview.id) {
                this.selectedReview = ''
            } else {
                this.selectedReview = e
            }
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('link-btn', {
    props: ['index', 'review'],
    template: `
        <a @click="change">{{ review.content }}</a>
    `,
    methods: {
        change() {
            this.$emit('updateIndex', this.index)
            this.$emit('updateReview', this.review)
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        added: [],
        movies: [
            {
                title: 'Regreso al futuro',
                desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Regreso al futuro',
                reviews: [
                    { id: 1, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 2, active: false },
                    { id: 2, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 3, active: false },
                    { id: 3, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 1, active: false }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Titanic',
                desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Titanic',
                reviews: [
                    { id: 1, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 2, active: false },
                    { id: 2, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 3, active: false },
                    { id: 3, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 1, active: false }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Blade Runner',
                desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Blade Runner',
                reviews: [
                    { id: 1, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 2, active: false },
                    { id: 2, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 3, active: false },
                    { id: 3, content: 'Blabla...', stars: 1, active: false }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to bubble up the selected reviews to the top level. I have added an `$emit` to the `updateR` method, and a handler on the `movie-card` tag that calls a new method, `updateReview`, which populates the appropriate element of `added`.

I just have it display `added`, but you could make your button show/hide a div that contains `added`.

```js
Vue.component('movie-card', {
  props: ['movie', 'title', 'description', 'review'],
  template: `
        <div>
            <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>
            <link-btn
                v-for="(review, index) in movie.reviews"
                :index="index"
                :review="review"
                key="review"
                @updateIndex="updateI($event)"
                @updateReview="updateR($event)">
            </link-btn>
            <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
        </div>
    `,
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: '',
      selectedReview: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateI(e) {
      if (e + 1 === this.selectedIndex) {
        this.selectedIndex = ''
      } else {
        this.selectedIndex = e + 1
      }
    },
    updateR(e) {
      if (e.id === this.selectedReview.id) {
        this.selectedReview = ''
      } else {
        this.selectedReview = e
      }
      this.$emit('update-review', this.selectedReview);
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('link-btn', {
  props: ['index', 'review'],
  template: `
        <a @click="change">{{ review.content }}</a>
    `,
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit('updateIndex', this.index)
      this.$emit('updateReview', this.review)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    added: [],
    movies: [{
        title: 'Regreso al futuro',
        desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Regreso al futuro',
        reviews: [{
            id: 1,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 2,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 3,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 1,
            active: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Titanic',
        desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Titanic',
        reviews: [{
            id: 1,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 2,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 3,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 1,
            active: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Blade Runner',
        desc: 'Esto es la descripción de Blade Runner',
        reviews: [{
            id: 1,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 2,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 3,
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            content: 'Blabla...',
            stars: 1,
            active: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateReview(index, review) {
      while (this.added.length < index) {
        this.added.push(null);
      }
      this.added.splice(index, 1, review);
      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <movie-card v-for="(movie, index) in movies" key="index" :movie="movie" :title="movie.title" :description="movie.desc" :review="movie.review" @update-review="updateReview(index, $event)">
  </movie-card>
  <a>BUTTON TO SHOW REVIEWS SELECTED</a>
  <div v-for="r, i in added">
    {{i}}: {{r}}
  </div>
</div>
```